# estimating the gradient of a harmonic function on a ball

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Given $u$ a harmonic function on a ball of radius $r$. i.e.

$$
-\Delta u=0 \qquad{\text{in $B_r(0)$}}
$$

Then show that 
$$
|\nabla u(0)|\leq C \frac{1}{r}\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{\partial B_r(0)}|u|
$$

It would be a great help if I could set some insight on how this inequality changes in case of a non-homogeneous equation and when there is a $p$-Laplacian.

Comment: @DavidC.UllrichThanks for the correction, I edited the question. Can you give me some reference for the proof?

Comment: It's easy from the Poisson integral formula (applied in, say,, $B(0,r/2)$.